# Positional $ working on different parts of the same document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following record:

```
r = {
    "_children" : {
        "addressesR" : [
            {
                "street" : "Bitton",
                "city" : "Perth",
                "id" : ObjectId("5317c149f45dfdb114deec41")
            },
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5317c149f45dfdb114deec42"),
                "street" : "Ivermey",
                "city" : "Perth",
        ],
    },
    "_searchData" : {
        "addressesR" : [
            {
                "street" : "BITTON",
                "city" : "PERTH",
                "id" : ObjectId("5317c149f45dfdb114deec41")
            },
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5317c149f45dfdb114deec42"),
                "street" : "IVERMEY",
                "city" : "PERTH",
            }
        ],
    },
}
```

Just save it:

```
db.p.save( r );
```

The record has two sub-documents: one has the list of children, and the other one has the identical list of children but in uppercase (for searching purposes).

When I update, I want to be able to update both. Now, this works:

```
db.p.update( { '$and': [ 
  { '_searchData.addressesR.street': 'BITTON' } ] },
  { '$set': {
    '_searchData.addressesR.$.street':'BITTON CHANGED' ,
    '_children.addressesR.$.street': 'Bitton CHANGED'
  }
})
```

The `$` operator is a positional operator. So, if the positions match, it will work fine. However, if the positions for any reasons mismatch, I suspect I am headed for disasters.

Now, considering that I always $push to those two arrays at the same time, and also that I $pull from them at the same time, within the same mongoDb query, should I be OK with this?

Also, is this going to work (see: positions will always always be the same) in an environment where the db has replication going on etc.?

(Note: this is the end result of an automatic mechanism that gets the children records within one record.)

Comment: I am thinking that maybe I should run two different updates, each one using `$elemMatch` to match the subset of arrays... Maybe that would be safer than assuming that the arrays never ever get out of sync position-wise?

Comment: Kind of is the way. I can only give you some notes on that and a future consideration as a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you comment you seem to be on the right track. As you are aware, the [positional **`$`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator is just a "value" container, that has the *index* of the first array element matched in your query.

You *"could"* use that if you were **absolutely** sure that your two arrays **always** contained the same number of elements and that these corresponding entries were in the same position at all times.

So yes, in order to be safe, use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) with **two** update operations like so

```js
db.p.update( { '$and': [ 
  { '_searchData.addressesR': {$elemMatch: { 'street': 'BITTON' } } ] },
  { '$set': {
    '_searchData.addressesR.$.street':'BITTON CHANGED' ,
  }
})

db.p.update( { '$and': [ 
  { '_children.addressesR': {$elemMatch: { 'street': 'Bitton' } } ] },
  { '$set': {
    '_children.addressesR.$.street': 'Bitton CHANGED'
  }
})
```

The only real consideration here is because of the two updates it is *possible* that a **read** of the document *could* occur in between those updates and your `_searchData` and `_children` documents would not have the same *corresponding* entries in the `addressesR` arrays.

Same thing applies with replication, as both operations have to be *replayed* by the secordary nodes.

What would be a nice feature, would be to be able to use $elemMatch in the *update* part of your query. In that way you would be querying for the position of the element on that side. But this doesn't exist **yet**. But from 2.6 upwards you **can** do something like this:

```js
db.runCommand({

    "update": "p",

    "updates": [
        { 
            "q": { '_children.addressesR': {$elemMatch: { 'street': 'Bitton' } },

            "u": { 
                "$set": {
                    "_children.addressesR.$.street": "Bitton CHANGED"
                }
            }
        },
        { 
            "q": { '_searchData.addressesR': {$elemMatch: { 'street': 'BITTON' } },

            "u": { 
                "$set": {
                    "_searchData.addressesR.$.street": "BITTON CHANGED"
                }
            }
        }

    ]
})
```

That is covered in the manual page under [Bulk Update](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/update/#bulk-update).